WWI Movie about a large ship?
There was a movie about a secret British female agent (supposedly OSA or MI5) tasked to defend a large passenger ship secretly carrying supplies for the Allies. While there is a German spy on board trying to sink it, the female agent and the German spy like each other not knowing who the other really is, and at the end of the movie a text appears claiming this ship lasted 52 minutes more than Titanic before sinking. The spy blows a bomb near the engine, and gets killed by the ships propelant.
I think it must be between 1998 and 2006, but more likely 2005 and 2000, and it was about 6 or 7 years ago at least, but I saw it in our national TV so this one won't help you it probably should have been 5 years old then. I don't know which country it was from but I guess it had to be British. But the movies timeline, I don't exactly remember if it was WWI or WWII.
Anyone knows the name of this movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Are there any other details that may help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details you might remember?

well the the spy blows a bomb near the engine , and gets killed by the ships propelant (i don't remember the right dictation!) , i think it must be between 1998 and 2006 , but more likely 2005 and 2000 , and it was about 6 or 7 years ago at least , but i saw it in our national tv so this one won't help u it probably should have been 5 years old then , and i don't know which country it was from but i guess it had to be british , but the movies timeline , i don't exactly remember it was WWI or WWII

Sounds like the 2000 film Britannic taking place in 1916 on HMHS Britannic where a British Intelligence agent called Vera Campbell is on board as well as a German spy posing as a chaplain who finds himself attracted to her. They find out each other's identity, he blows a hole in the side of the ship and in the end he commits suicide. You probably misremembered the caption in the end of the movie, that reads:
"The Britannic sank in 57 minutes, half the time of the Titanic."
Here's the trailer:




well it was long ago i don't remember some movies as i should , some times i even remember the movie but don't remember the avtors , so i get surprised when i watch it after a long time :D any way thanx , people here are nice , i just post questions on yahoo answers and they just get deleted :|

No problem. :) Not sure what Yahoo rules are, but your question was thorough and supplied plenty of details, which is much appreciated around here.

well yahoo doesn't have rules it seems because anyone that doesn't like the question reports it!! i asked that can some game be hacked so the number of inventory slots get increased , it's almost called modding , then it undergoes for review :| but your answer was well explained , and from what i saw while crawling between questions , you are a true movied geek :D

@Hitman2847 Then be sure to check out the corresponding SE site for your game question: [gaming.se]. Though, I don't know if your question would be on-topic there, but I would think so.

@NapoleonWilson thanx , that may help if gamers on this site would be this kind too :)
